# I need to move 'beforeEach' and 'afterEach' from spec to global config WDIO [mocha, hook, wdio]

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, hook, wdio-v6

I use **WebdriverIO** for E2E testing with **mocha** framework

When I run tests, I want that after the first error, all subsequent checks in this test were skipped, and Mocha went to the next test file

as an example, I showed the code below which needs to be taken out from each test file and applied globally.

---

I need to move **beforeEach** and *afterEach* from spec to global config WDIO [mocha, hook, wdio]

I need to move code from spec to global config WDIO

The main goal is to skip the tests after though the test in it has failed

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('Verify next it is skipped', function () {
    let skipNextIt = false;
    beforeEach(function () {
        if (skipNextIt) {
            this.skip();
        }
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        if(this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
            skipNextIt = true;
        }
    });

    it('is should pass', function () {
        expect(true).to.equal(true);
    });

    it('is should fail', function () {
        expect(true).to.equal(false);
    });

    it('is should skipp 1', function () {
        expect(true).to.equal(true);
    });

    it('is should skipp 2', function () {
        expect(true).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: what is wdio? what did you tried so far? do you get an error? please explain more

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [bail](https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks#bail)([mocha doc](https://mochajs.org/#-bail-b))?

Once a test within a spec fails, exit the spec.

FYI: add next time your WDIO version.

Comment: (Don't forget to ▲ Upvote answers that are helpful and to ✓＋▲ Accept and Upvote an answer that helped you solve your problem!)